# Laravel Excel launch error on spreadsheets that have more than 20 rows

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm currently working on a project which allows users to upload a `.xlxs` format file, which contains a lot of rows.
I used `Laravel-excel 3.1 maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"` to develop this task.
The thing is that everything works fine if`.xlsx` file have less than 20 rows.
But if the file has more than 20 rows, laravel excel throws the following merror message:

`Argument 1 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\ModelManager::Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\{closure}() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCF-CRM\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php on line 245`

I tried to change the request file as I saw in different sites on internet, but nothing worked.

The error message says that RedirectResponse is the problem. But just can't figure out why (I think it is matter of the size of the file).
I tried to increase upload values settings on php.ini but didn't work.

I also thought to upload file first and later import it to laravel-excel as an existing file on server. But don´t know how to do that.

Controller function:

```
public function upload_base (Request $request){ 
         
        $request->validate([
            'base_xls' => 'required|mimes:xlsx, csv, xls'
        ]);  

        Base_comercial::truncate();  
        Excel::import(new BaseComercialImport, request()->file('base_xls')->store('temp'));  
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', '¡Base comercial cargada exitosamente!');
}
```

Import class:

```
    /** 
    * @param array $row
    * 
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)  
    {
        /* id estado converter */
        $estado = $this->estado_validate($row['estado']);
        if ($estado == "ERROR"){
            return redirect()->back()->with('Error', '¡Estado inválido!');
        } 
        /* --- */
        return new Base_comercial([ 
            'fecha' => Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha']),
            'nom_cliente' => $row['cliente'],
            'nom_proyecto' => $row['nom_proy'], 
            'cod_cc' => $row['cod_cc'],
            'valor_proyecto' => $row['vr_proy'],
            'com_1' => $row['com1'],
            'com_2' => $row['com2'],
            'com_3' => $row['com3'],
            'id_estado' => $estado,
            'fecha_inicio' => Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['f_inicio']),
            'dura_mes' => Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['dura_mes']),
            'id_user' => Auth::user()->id,
        ]); 
    }

    public function estado_validate ($estado){
        switch ($estado){
            case "CERRADO":
                $estado = 1;
                break;
            case "COTIZACION":
                $estado = 2;
                break;
            case "EJECUCIONXFACTURAR":
                $estado = 3;
                break;
            case "PERDIDO":
                $estado = 4;
                break;
            case "PROPUESTA":
                $estado = 5;
                break;
            case "VENTA":
                $estado = 6;
                break;
            case "VENTAEJECUCIÓN":
                $estado = 7;
                break;
            default: 
                $estado = "ERROR";                                 
            break;
        }
        return $estado;
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/base-upload', [ComercialController::class, 'upload_base'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('base-upload');
```

UPDATE
I managed to save the xlsx file on the server and then import it. However, I get the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made it. It just was an accent mark (´) on estado validate function. So, when $estado = "ERROR" a redirect is fired. This redirect is causing the problem.